# Can I put a font-awesome icon inside a triangular div?

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N67Ce.png)I drew a triangular div using borders, can't I flow the icon so it would be inside the div?

```css
div#sub-footer div {
  border-color: transparent transparent #2BD5B4 transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px 30px 30px 30px;
  margin-bottom: -0.5px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

div#sub-footer div a {
  float: left;
}

div#line {
  width:100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #394C5F;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post rest of `HTML` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put anything in a div and make it look like a triangle. Here I have removed the borders from the container div and applied the transparent border triangle trick to a pseudo element on that container div (`.triangle:before`). Centered the icon using absolute centering but you could just as easily use flexbox or other techniques to achieve a centered layout.

```css
.triangle {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  width: 60px;
}
.triangle:before {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 30px solid transparent;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 40px solid #2BD5B4;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.triangle a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="triangle">
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></a>
</div>
```